# ViewGroup with nested ViewGroup

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm facing with a strange problem.
For example, we have this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f00"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Our screen will become black. Same result if I replace LinearLayout with FrameLayout or ConstraintLayout.

But if replace first LinearLayout with RelativeLayout the screen will be red!
In my case I need behavior like RelativeLayout, but should use LinearLayout. 
How it is possible?
Big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f00"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If super parent is LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout change `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"` to `android:layout_weight="1"` and remove other unnecessary codes. If super parent is Relative Layout then just remove only the "weight" parameter and add the following.

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: I need linear layout in the center of constraint layout :(

Comment: Well in that case I just edited my code. Please try this.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not go through your original question carefully. Now I am not sure what your final layout (after adding additional views) will look like. Based on your comment that the linear layout should behave like the relative layout, and what I saw the relative layout is just filling up the entire space ("whole screen red"). I just modified  the code. I checked the code in studio it is doing as you described.

Comment: Thank you, its works. But what if superparent container is not ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I added  the code for linear and relative layout in my answer.